# Can't export .bacpac file of Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, .net-4.8

While I am trying to use the export data-tier application option to create a backpack file I am getting error as I have sequences in my database. I have a lot's of them. I need to export the database with the sequences. Is there any way? I need to send my database to my teacher. he would import this database on his Microsoft SQL Server management studio.

The error details:

```
Error SQL71564: The element Sequence: [dbo].[MsgTbl_seq] is not supported when used as part of a data package (.bacpac file)
```

Comment: The error is pretty specific. Do you really need to export the data? Or can you create a DACPAC instead?

Comment: I need to export the data. Sorry, I do not understand what DACPAC is.

Comment: If you need the data why not take a backup? A DACPAC only contains the schema, a BACPAC the schema and data. You can read more about them [here](is not supported when used as part of a data package ). A backup on the other hand is a disk-level, consistent and often compressed copy of the database and has no restrictions.

Comment: have you shared a link [here]. it shows as a plain text. Are you advising me to create a backup? how to do that would I be able to share the tables, sequences and the data with the backup file?

Comment: `would I be able to share...`: a backup can help you if your target environment is the same as your source environment and these support restore of backup file - for example if both are SQL Server on-premises. But if you want to migrate data and schema between different environments or to older version then backup will probably not fit (for example from on-premises to Azure DB).

Comment: (2) In the title you speak about `export` but in the content you speak about `extract data-tier application`  -these are two different task. The first create bacpac file and the second create dacpac file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIfax.png

Comment: @RonenAriely Sorry It would be export not extract. btw would dacpac or extracting help me in this situation. I need to send my database to my teacher. he would import this database on his Microsoft SQL Server management studio.

Comment: `I need to send my database to my teacher.`: (1) There should be no direct issue to create backpc and dacpac files when you have Sequence. Sequence is supported in SQL Server on premises and in Azure Database as well. More information is needed to understand your issue. (2) If this is database on premises then you should send him a backup file of the DB and not bacpac. It will be simpler for him to use (assuming he have the same version of the server or a newer version).

Comment: This scenario which use Sequence: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROQnE.png is fully supported for bacpac.

Comment: @RonenAriely I have created sequence exactly in that way you have shown. But if my database even have one single sequence it does not work(export data-tier application). I give me an error "Error SQL71564: The element Sequence: [dbo].[MsgTbl_seq] is not supported when used as part of a data package (.bacpac file)"
but if I use the option export data-tier application option on a database that does not have sequence it works and gives not error.

Comment: What version of SSMS (check SSMS "help"->"about") the and what version of SQL Server you use (execute: "select @@version"). I recommend to move the discussion to [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/SQLServer.AzureSQLDBandMI) or to [Microsoft Forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/58065/sql-server-general.html) where we can add screenshot and have real discussion. Not like this poor interface of comments.